# how to use JavaScript with react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to use javascript insted of typescript?
when ever i create react native app by using npx react-native init ,i get typescript insted of javascript.
any idea guys?

i could not find anything online

Answer (score 2):

### [Using JavaScript Instead of TypeScript](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript)

React Native defaults new applications to TypeScript, but JavaScript may still be used. Files with a .jsx extension are treated as JavaScript instead of TypeScript, and will not be typechecked. JavaScript modules may still be imported by TypeScript modules, along with the reverse.

Comment: so there is no way to use --template

Comment: You don't need a template as it allows both. all you have to do is replace the .ts files with .js and delete the files for typescript like tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Using expo and `npx create-expo-app`command let me to create a react native app with js. For more info [click here](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/introduction/)

Comment: I don't want to use expo